# Non static can follow Static, but Static can't follow non-static?

Tags: c, static

I have 2 questions:

1. This is my code which compiles and links correctly

```
//driver.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int lib_x = 1;
static void libc_func();

void libc_func(){
    lib_x += 11;
}

int main(){
    lib_x += 5;
    printf("%d\n",lib_x);
    libc_func();
    printf("%d\n",lib_x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is as expected

```
6
17
```

However, when I switch things up and the code is

```
//driver.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int lib_x = 1;
void libc_func();

static void libc_func(){
    lib_x += 11;
}

int main(){
    lib_x += 5;
    printf("%d\n",lib_x);
    libc_func();
    printf("%d\n",lib_x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get a compilation error which states

```
driver.c:7:13: error: static declaration of ‘libc_func’ follows non-static declaration
 static void libc_func(){
             ^~~~~~~~~
driver.c:5:6: note: previous declaration of ‘libc_func’ was here
 void libc_func();
```

I don't get **why no error shows up when a non-static declaration follows a static declaration**, but an error shows up the other way round. Can someone explain this situation?

2. Another thing which I noticed was there is a different behavior when it comes to variables
   When compiling this code:

```
//driver.c
int lib_x;
static int lib_x = 2;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

the error is:

```
driver.c:3:12: error: static declaration of ‘lib_x’ follows non-static declaration
 static int lib_x = 2;
            ^~~~~
driver.c:2:5: note: previous declaration of ‘lib_x’ was here
 int lib_x;
```

and when compiling this code:

```
//driver.c
static int lib_x;
int lib_x = 2;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

the error is:

```
driver.c:3:5: error: non-static declaration of ‘lib_x’ follows static declaration
 int lib_x = 2;
     ^~~~~
driver.c:2:12: note: previous declaration of ‘lib_x’ was here
 static int lib_x;
```

So variables show error when non-static follows static & static follows non-static. However, **functions only show error when static follows non-static**. What could explain this difference in treatment between variables and functions?

Comment: Read about tentative definition.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with C is that when it was standardized in 1989 the standard committee had to take care that the compilers would also successfully compile lots of existing code that varied in its conventions. Therefore the keywords `static` and `extern` and their interactions are a bit convoluted...

- The code

  ```
   int lib_x;
   static int lib_x = 2;
  ```

  does not work [C11/18 6.2.2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2), because the first `int lib_x;` is a tentative definition with *external linkage*, whereas the `static int lib_x = 2;` is a definition with *internal linkage*. Then, as per 6.2.2p7,

  > 7 If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

  Some C compilers might let this to compile, but your compiler errors out.

  As for

  ```
    static int lib_x;
    int lib_x = 2;
  ```

  The first is a tentative definition with *internal* linkage, and the rule for the 2nd is rather complicated

  > 4 For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,31) if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

  > 5 If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`. If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

  Because it did **not** have a storage specifier its linkage will be **external**. Now the confusing part is that if it **did** have `extern` storage class specifier it would have worked!

  ```
  static int lib_x;
  extern int lib_x = 2;
  ```
- For the function case, the same text applies; only now the first part of 6.2.2p5 applies, which says that *any* function declaration without a storage specifier is as if it *were* declared with `extern`, i.e. the latter would correspond to exactly

  ```
  extern void libc_func();

  static void libc_func(){
      lib_x += 11;
  }
  ```

  and it does not work, because the *first*, in absence of any prior declaration, would specify *external linkage*, and the second specifies internal linkage; but switching the 2 would work, because

  ```
  static void libc_func(){
      lib_x += 11;
  }

  extern void libc_func();
  ```

  the `extern` in fact there again means "prior linkage, or extern if not specified before*.

Answer (score 1):

Things to know: *External* linkage is the default one when you declare a variable and a declaration always comes before a definition.

**Function case**

In your first case, you first declare lib_func() as static and then you define it without specifying a storage classifier (static or extern). However, the compiler knows because of your previous declaration that lib_func() has static linkage so it doesn't have to "guess" that lib_func() storage classifier.

In the second case, you first declare a variable with external linkage (since you don't specify a storage classifier again) but then the compiler sees a static storage classifier in the definition of lib_func(). Since declaration comes before a definition, these are contradictive.

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler guess for variables then?